# SwipeRefresh with ScrollView and FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, floating-action-button

I am trying to implement SwipeRefreshLayout for Floating Button and scrollview with three TableLayouts. I want to show Floating Button all the time on the screen(like it is on Gmail app with Material Design). Unfortunately swipe-refresh is blocking scrolling up. How to inform swipe-refresh that my scrollview want to scroll up? Should I change layout structure?

I am using library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_recent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_recent_claims"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_recent_rapidscans"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_recent_journeys"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/fab_plus24" />
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `canChildScrollUp()` method programmatically for your `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Each case is different, depending on the child View you have under the `SwipreRefreshLayout`.

Also, I believe that the `FrameLayout`is unnecessary in your case, and could be intercepting the scrollability of the `ScrollView`

Google offers some samples for both the resources and code that could be used to correctly implement a `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

One view: https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshListFragment/index.html

Multiple views: https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/index.html